# How to test react component having css transition?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Below are the two method I am using to change the state of the popup wrapper.

```
const waitTransitionEnd = (element) => new Promise(resolve => {
  const onEnd = () => {
    element.removeEventListener('transitionend', onEnd)
    resolve()
  }
  element.addEventListener('transitionend', onEnd)
})
    doOpen () {
        const dialog = findDOMNode(this.dialog)
        this.setState({ status: OPENING })
        return waitTransitionEnd(dialog).then(() => {
          this.setState({ status: OPENED })
          this.focus()
        })
      }
      doClose () {
        const dialog = findDOMNode(this.dialog)
        this.setState({ status: CLOSING })
        return waitTransitionEnd(dialog).then(() => {
          this.setState({ status: CLOSED })
        })
      }
```

So the dialog is  styled component with the css transition. I am trying to test the component I am getting status only opening as opened state is coming only after transition has been completed. I am using jest snapshot testing. Any one faced such kind of issue while writing test cases with jest? Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate the transitionEnd event like any other React event.

If you're using Enzyme it would look something like:

```
test('should do something after transition ends', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component>Label text</Component>);
    expect(wrapper).toHaveState('status', OPENED);
    wrapper.simulate('transitionEnd');
    expect(wrapper).toHaveState('status', CLOSED);
});
```

Additionally, you may want to add your transition events right your component:

```
const Component = () => 
     <div onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd} onClick={startStatusTransition} />
```